Model badly deformed after opening the blend file again
I started making a table using reference photos yesterday. I just added 3 photos, the plane(which i worked on it), and a mirror modifier. I saved it, closed my pc, and today i opened the project and the model looks like this.
It happened again in a previous file i made 2 days ago, but i thought that the blend file may be corrupt.
Is there any way to solve this? I haven't lost a lot of work. But it will be nice the reason it might happened, and the way to fix it.
Thank you!
Edit:I uploaded the blend file. And the model was fixed somehow when i reopened for 3rd time the blend file. So now it's ok.


I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. It would also be helpful to see a screenshot of the whole of your Blender window which you can do via Window > Save Screenshot in Blender and then edit into your question.

Hello thanks for your reply!
I edited my question and added the file.
Although i reopened the blend file and for some reason it is now fixed.

Ah ok. It certainly looks ok although you might apply the Scale and Rotation to it in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Rotation & Scale) just in case that was causing problems.

Thank you very much!
I will have it on mind!
